# How to output successful tests from `lein test`?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, clojure-testing

Using clojure.test, when running `lein test`, the default settings only print out the number of assertions, like "Ran 12 tests containing 19 assertions," the details for failed tests, and the namespaces tested.  I would like an output of the successful tests as well, so I can see what tests were actually run.  Frameworks like Mocha in JS have this behavior by default.

For instance, if the following test passed:

```
(deftest aTest
  (testing "Simple test"
      (is (= 1 1))))
```

I would like an output like (formatting is arbitrary):

```
Testing <namespace>
    Passed: aTest -> Simple test
```

Ideally, the passed test would also be color coded.

I looked at a few libraries, including lein-test-refresh and humane-test-output, but didn't see what I needed.  The other option looks like to rewrite the report function in clojure.test, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have searched multiple times for an answer to this question, so here is a complete solution building on @ivan-grishaev's hint using [Test Report](https://github.com/redbadger/test-report):

Test Report hooks into `clojure.test` to provide custom reporters that are then being run with every event occuring through a test run. Those events are passed as maps called "messages". The minimal example just applies`clojure.pprint/pprint` to the messages, but this only gets you so far. Here is a bit more code to give you a feel how to write custom reporters. The `indenting-reporter` indents test namespaces, `deftest`s and `testing` vars, and lists them all independent of test outcome.

Create a file like this in your project:

```
(ns my.own.test-reporter
  (:require [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]
            [clojure.test :as ct]
            [clojure.core.match :refer [match]]))

(defn simple-reporter [msg]
  (pprint msg))

(defn indenting-reporter [msg]
  (match (:type msg)
         :begin-test-ns (println (str "Testing " (:ns msg) "\n"))
         :begin-test-var (println (str "  " (-> msg :var meta :name)))
         :pass (do (println (str "    " (-> msg :context first) " :pass"))
                   (ct/inc-report-counter :pass))
         :fail (do (println (str "    " (-> msg :context first) " :fail"))
                   (ct/inc-report-counter :fail))
         :error (do (println (str "    " (-> msg :context first) " :error"))
                    (ct/inc-report-counter :error))
         :end-test-ns (println)
         :end-test-var ()
         :summary (pprint msg)
         :else (pprint msg)))
```

and then use it in the `:test` profile of your `project.clj`:

```
:injections [(require '[my.own.test-reporter :as tr])]
:test-report {:reporters [tr/indenting-reporter]}
```

You could now go on an add color to the outputs.

Comment: Thank you! That was a very nice reply! I'd only replace `match` by `case` to not depend on a non core lib.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to write it yourself. If you would like an example of how to leverage the existing `deftest` into a custom macro, here is an example [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo) that automatically picks a "name" for the deftest group based on the line number:

```
(defmacro dotest [& body]
  (let [test-name-sym (symbol (str "dotest-line-" (:line (meta &form))))]
  `(clojure.test/deftest ~test-name-sym ~@body)))

(dotest
  (is (= 5 (+ 2 3))))  ; works!
```

You could just add in a `println` and *voila!*

Answer (score 1):

I remember, the [Eftest library](https://github.com/weavejester/eftest) provides nice colored output when running tests, you may take a look.

Also, the standard `clojure.test` framework supports adding your own reports. Check the [Test report](https://github.com/redbadger/test-report) library for the reference.

Probably, when running the tests from your editor or IDE, it could provide the colored output. Here is my Cider-powered Emacs screenshot with the failure report:

[image]